# How to set the default VLAN on Cisco SG350 switches firmware 2.5.0.83

Tags: vlan, cisco-sg300

We've got a site with all its Cisco SG300 network switches configured with a custom default VLAN.

Normally, we'd use the following commands to change the default VLAN:

```
vlan database
default-vlan vlan 11
exit
```

That definitely worked in firmware v1.4.8.6, but the command is missing in firmware v2.5.0.83 and I've got no idea what the equivalent is in the new firmware.

Comment: Have you created that VLAN first? Note that the default VLAN is only reassigned to ports falling out of LAG and similar. I think you could really mean changing the *native*, untagged or access VLAN for all ports.

Comment: @Zac67, yes - the default VLAN would be the native VLAN that all ports on a switch will deafult to without any configuration overriding it.  The default VLAN is also referenced in smartport configuration.  Other switches on the network are setup with a default vlan of 11, and without being able to change that on the SG350, the switch will complain of a mismatched default VLAN... or maybe the message is actually referring to native VLAN, I'd have to check.